# Ocultar botón al cambiar de propiedad

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto Java, el cual tiene roles. Al iniciarlo me carga el rol invitado por defecto. Pretendo hacer un botón para desloguearse, pero que solamente los que estén logueados puedan verlo, es decir, que esté escondido cuando se es invitado, y cuando el rol cambie el botón se ponga visible de nuevo. Cuando un usuario se loguea, el rol cambia.

Lo planteo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void _desconectarbtPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                              

   if(Main.rol=="invitado"){
       this._desconectarbt.hide();
   }
   else{
       this._desconectarbt.setVisible(true);
           }
}
```

No sé si lo he planteado mal, pero el if me lo coge, porque al iniciar la aplicación, el botón se esconde, pero luego no me lo vuelve a poner visible, una vez el usuario está logueado.

¿En qué fallo?

Gracias.

Comment: de qué clase es tu **_desconectarbt** ?

Comment: javax.swing.JButton

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero tal vez te hace falta "actualizar la app" después de hacer visible el botón de nuevo: después de setVisible(true); intentando con un revalidate **((JPanel)c.getParent()).revalidate();**

Comment: Si no funciona el consejo de @PakLeiChong intente haciendo un paint() para refrescar la ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero usar el método `equals()` para comparar la cadena y no usar `==` para realizar la comparación :

```
private void _desconectarbtPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                              

   if(Main.rol.equals("invitado")){
       this._desconectarbt.hide();
   }else{
       this._desconectarbt.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

de esta forma se realizará correctamente la comparación y pueda mostrar y esconder el elemento correctamente.